# How to sum column after the last row of data?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub test   
    Dim VR As Long
    VR = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2,0).Formula = "=sum(j2:J" & VR")"
end sub
```

I am trying to sum up Column J and VBA is making this line red. The values to be added start in cell j2 and the last row in column j with data. How do I fix this line?

Comment: add a space and  `&` after `VR`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Basically, just a minor typo in your formula. Added and ampersand.

Also I specified which worksheets it all is to happen in with the we variable.

```
Sub test()
 Dim ws as worksheet
 Dim VR as Long
 Dim rng as Range

 Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets(“Sheet1”)
 With ws
     VR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
 End with

 Set rng = ws.Cells((VR+1), 10)
 
 rng.Offset(2,0).Formula = “=SUM(J2:J” & VR & “)”

End sub
```